# Possible bug in Excel.Interop's Worksheet.UsedRange property?

Tags: c#, excel

Take a gander at the following code. Basically, this is a function that gets called in order to identify the used range of a worksheet, loop through that range, and hash social security numbers.

Here's the problem. If I create a spreadsheet and populate one cell, the function does not hash that cell. However, if I populate more than one, it works.

Could this be a bug in the UsedRange property? Or am I missing something?

thanks much.

Woody

```cs
try
{
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in _excelWorksheet)
    {
        // Grab the range of numbers that populates the XLS.
        Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;
        // In the following cases, Value2 returns different types:
        //
        // 1. The range variable points to a single cell:
        // Value2 returns a object
        //
        // 2. The range variable points to many cells:
        // Value2 returns object[,]

        object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

        for (int row = 1; row <= values.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
            for (int col = 1; col <= values.GetUpperBound(1); col++)
            {
                // Convert values to strings.
                string value = Convert.ToString(values[row, col]);

                // Mask the value that we retrieved and store it in a variable.
                switch (_mdOptions.cbobxEncryption.Text)
                {
                    case "MD5":
                    {
                        replaceSSN = SHA2Hash.ComputeHash(value, "MD5", null);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "SHA256":
                    {
                        replaceSSN = SHA2Hash.ComputeHash(value, "SHA256", null);
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                        replaceSSN = SHA2Hash.ComputeHash(value, "SHA256", null);
                        break;
                    }
                }    

                // Match expressions to sensitive data and replace with the hash
                // value.
                if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"\b[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\b"))
                {
                    range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, replaceSSN);
                }
                else if (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"\b[0-9]{3}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}\b"))
                {
                    range.Cells.set_Item(row, col, replaceSSN);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // This is here because of a non-fatal error that we're getting with
        // Windows 7 during the hashing phase. Everything still works,
        // it's just that this error keeps popping up.

        // REVIEW FOR WINDOWS 7 COMPATABILITY
        ;

        //MessageBox.Show("There was a major error. Please restart the program.");
        //MessageBox.Show(@"Exception: " + ee);
    }


    // Pull the hashed password from the registry and add it to the SaveAs
    //string saveAsPassword = Convert.ToString(Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mask Data", "Password", ""));
    /*
    _excelWorkbook.SaveAs("Results.xls",
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, false,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
    Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 
     */
     // Report success.    
    MessageBox.Show("File masked successfully.", 
        "Mask Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 
        MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
    // Shutdown instance of Excel.
    //_excelApp.Quit();

    // Release memory.
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelWorkbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excelApp);         
}
```

Comment: When it is a single cell, what does values look like?  Is it definitely correctly creating the correct array in order for the for loops to iterate?

Comment: I'm getting an InvalidCastException when there's only one cell populated... "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Object[,]'."

I don't understand why that is.

Comment: I understand that the number is a double... but int should work regardless... at least that's my understanding. So I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't convert a double to a 2 dimensional array of objects, if only because a double has only 1 dimension.  Apologies if I am telling you something you already know but the term 'double' means double precision, and has nothing to do with 2 dimensional arrays (as defined by object[,]).

You could simply add a check for this case so the first few lines would look like:

```
XLS.Excel.Range range = ws.UsedRange;
object[,] values;
if (range.Value2.GetType().IsArray)
{
    values = (object[,])range.Value2;
}
else
{
    values = new object[2,2];
    values[1,1] = range.Value2;
}
```

I don't have VS on this machine so the code is untested but should be pretty close

**EDIT:**
Having knocked up a quick test app I can see what UsedRange.Value2 is doing - it returns an array of all of the sheet values which is why if there is more than 1 cell it is an array however for one cell it will just return that value (which could be any type).  The code above will work however is a bit of a hack.  The correct way to get the number of rows and columns is using:

```
range.Rows.Count
```

and

```
range.Columns.Count
```

If you change your for loops to use these 2 values rather than the array bounds it will solve your problem, and will work for both single and multiple rows

Comment: thanks Macros... I think I'm getting it... however, when I run the code, I get an error that I can't apply the ! operand to an object... how else can I write it. I've tried a couple different ways, but then I get more issues...

Comment: BTW, I've only been writing C# code for a year off and on, so sorry if this seems like a no-brainer...

Comment: I've knocked up a quick test app and looked into it further, please see edited answer

Comment: I was wrong... it doesn't work... what's happening is when it gets to <pre><code>values = new object[2,2]; while debugging it, the values are null -- 0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1 are all null... then the error gets thrown...

Comment: I've edited again and assigned the value to the position 1,1 of the array which lookw like the ony one you are checking?

Comment: No actually, it's checking the entire UsedRange... I think it's working now. I've placed one instance of an SSN in various spots and they hash correctly each time... thanks bud.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment in your code, the Value2 property returns a single text / number / logical / error value for a single cell or object[,] for multiple cells.

Comment: But that's just it... maybe I'm simply confused, but it's a double and it's supposed to be cast as an object... so why isn't it working???

Comment: If you have a double boxed as an object and try to cast it to object[,], the expected behavior is an InvalidCastException. You need to check (range.Value2 is object[,]) before casting, or use (range.Value2 as object[,]) which will yield null if it is not object[,]. Of course, you should save the value returned from range.Value2 in a local variable so as not to allocate it twice.